# html form path: how to fix the relative starting point?

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx

This seems to have different behavior depending on browsers which drives crazy.

On my server, I have nginx forward to an apache docker container.

```
location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2/;
}
```

On apache container, I have "/var/www/html/index.html" which has the following form.

```
<form action="act.php?action=add_item" method="post" ...
```

and I have corresponding "/var/www/html/act.php".

On some browser, it works perfect when I access "http://.../foo/" and the submit goes correctly. But on others, it doesn't work and I have to modify like this,

```
<form action="foo/act.php?action=add_item" method="post" ...
```

i.e., I have to attach "foo/". I don't know why, is there a way to fix this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I don't get it... you are doing `action="act.php[...]"` on `/foo` ???? But are you in `/index.html` ??? Either way, try using `action="/act.php[...]"` and see...

Comment: This doesn't work in either case. I've tested.

Comment: I repeat, please, explain exactly what you are accessing... you tell us that you are using `index.html` but you are accessing it by going to `/foo` instead of `/index.html` ???? Makes no sense... Explain that please...

Comment: If you don't understand how nginx forwading works, then probably you should not make comments. My question is clear enough.

Comment: Oh no, my bad, I totally missed that part at the top... you should always go absolute path, because then, you have this strange behavior... if you access `/foo` that goes to the docker `index.html`, and inside you have the `action` to go to `act.php` that is in the same `root` as `index.html`, you should do `/foo/act.php` to prevent that strange behavior, but that will only work if you are accessing that page through `/foo`.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Now it is accessed correctly on different browsers.

Comment: You are welcome, remember that you are accessing it through `/foo`, so you will not be able to go to `/act.php` if you are not accessing it through `/foo/act.php` because that is your rewrite/proxy to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change

```
<form action="act.php?action=add_item" method="post" ...
```

To

```
<form action="/foo/act.php?action=add_item" method="post" ...
```

This is because that page is accessed through `/foo`, so if you try to see `/act.php` you won't be able, because you are routing/proxing/rewriting to `/foo` to be able to see it. So correct path is absolute to `/foo/act.php`.